# Remove/add part of image src on click with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two buttons that show two types of gallery view. When I click on the landscape button, I want to loop throw all the images in the gallery div and remove the '_500x500_acf_cropped' part of the source. Then if I click on the grid button I want to add that back into the source, allowing me to toggle the two views.

What is the best way to achieve this please? My script works, but it copies the first img src and replaces them all which is not what I wanted to happen

```
<button class="grid"><img src="grid.png" alt="Grid View" /></button>
<button class="landscape"><img src="grid-landscape.png" alt="Landscape View" /></button> 

<section class="gallery">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="gallery-image col-md-4"><a href="2017/05/2014-044-192-819x1024.jpg" target="_blank" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery"><img src="2017/05/2014-044-192_500x500_acf_cropped.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
  <div class="gallery-image col-md-4"><a href="2017/05/2014-002-086-1024x680.jpg" target="_blank" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery"><img src="2017/05/2014-002-086_500x500_acf_cropped.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
  <div class="gallery-image col-md-4"><a href="/2017/05/2014-002-084-1024x680.jpg" target="_blank" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery"><img src="2017/05/2014-002-084_500x500_acf_cropped.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
 </div>
</section>
<script>
$(".landscape").click(function(){
var fullimgurl = $('.gallery-image img').attr('src');
fullimgurl = fullimgurl.replace('_500x500_acf_cropped','');
$(.gallery-image img).attr("src", fullimgurl);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried. The [documentation for jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) has many, many examples, as does [our own Documentation effort](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jquery/topics).

Comment: Sorry ive added my script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```js
document.querySelector('.landscape').addEventListener('click',()=>{
  document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-image img').forEach(function(el){
    var fullimgurl = el.src
    fullimgurl = fullimgurl.replace('_500x500_acf_cropped','');
    el.src = fullimgurl;
  })
})
```

```html
<button class="grid"><img src="grid.png" alt="Grid View" /></button>
    <button class="landscape"><img src="grid-landscape.png" alt="Landscape View" /></button> 
    
    <section class="gallery">
     <div class="row">
      <div class="gallery-image col-md-4"><a href="2017/05/2014-044-192-819x1024.jpg" target="_blank" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery"><img src="2017/05/2014-044-192_500x500_acf_cropped.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
      <div class="gallery-image col-md-4"><a href="2017/05/2014-002-086-1024x680.jpg" target="_blank" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery"><img src="2017/05/2014-002-086_500x500_acf_cropped.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
      <div class="gallery-image col-md-4"><a href="/2017/05/2014-002-084-1024x680.jpg" target="_blank" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery"><img src="2017/05/2014-002-084_500x500_acf_cropped.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
     </div>
    </section>
```

(also, there are missing quotes in your "$(.gallery-image img)")

Comment: That does, how do I do the reverse so that when the click the other button (.grid) that it adds _500x500_acf_cropped back to the src please?

Comment: document.querySelector('.grid').addEventListener('click',()=>{
  document.querySelectorAll('.gallery-image img').forEach(function(el){
    var fullimgurl = el.src
    fullimgurl = fullimgurl.replace('.jpg','_500x500_acf_cropped.jpg');
    el.src = fullimgurl;
  })
})

Comment: Sorry just to make this more complicated. If I double click .grid it will show missing images as it keeps adding '_500x500_acf_cropped.jpg, is there a way to check if it already contains that do nothing?